# mysql join two different tables

Tags: php, mysql, left-join

I have two tables in my MySql database:

```
user    
- sid
- userid
- username

log
- sid
- userid
- login_time
```

As you can guess, there's a lot more records in log tables than in user table.
I am using php to present these records on my website in a table format as shown below.

```
no  |  userid |  username  |  number of login  |
1   |  inzo   |  harvey    |        233        |
2   |  chae   |  schmidts  |        433        |
3   |  hibro  |  swainy    |        12         |
```

To get the **number of login** for each user, I can send another queries in a for statement. But it's consuming resources and making the server slow in the end.

Can I have this result in one single join query?

Comment: include what you have tried. then you will get solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, you have to use count the logins for each user with a `group by`

```
select  t1.userid, t1.username, count(t2.sid)
from    user t1
left join
        log t2
on      t1.userid = t2.userid
group by t1.userid, t1.username
```

The `left join` ensures you that users without logins will still be returned, wit 0 as count.

**Edit**

About the question in the comment: if you want to only count the logins with a specific flag value, you can just add `where flag = x` before the `group by`; if you want to have a separate count for each value of the flag, you have to add that flag to both `group by` and `select`.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Zanini, what if there's another column 'flag' (eg: 0 or 1) in log table, and I need reference flag column to get the number of login. I mean I need WHERE clause to get count(t2.sid) ??

Comment: Edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

I guess best and by that I mean least resource consuming way would be to add "number_of_login" to user table and just increase it every time he/she is logged in, because any other solution will require looping

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TABLE_A.row_id, TABLE_A.category, TABLE_A.val_1, TABLE_B.val_2
FROM TABLE_B
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE_A ON TABLE_B.row_id = TABLE_A.row_id
ORDER BY row_id;
```

If you want all the results, you need an outer join, not an inner one.

Answer (score 0):

select a.sid,a.userid,a.username,COUNT(b.sid) from user a 
Left join log b ON b.sid =a.sid group by a.sid